# Unrecognized selector sent to instance, Working with Json Data & OnConnect API

Tags: objective-c, json

In my app, I am calling API from OnConnect and I am having trouble passing key object from JSon data to NSArray to populate tableview.

My breakpoint come to where I pass objectAtIndex to tableview row. Can anyone please suggest me whether I am accessing JSon data shown in the screenshot properly. This is my first try with JSon and API.

Please see my code and API response below for details:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[movieslist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"startTime"];

> -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd673bb0

[{
    "startTime": "2013-08-18T12:10Z",
    "endTime": "2013-08-18T14:35Z",
    "duration": 145,
    "ratings": [{
        "body": "Motion Picture Association of America",
        "code": "PG"
    }],
```

Answer (score 1):

You should print out your `moviesList` and make sure you are getting what you are expecting.

However you are getting the data, it is returning an NSDictionary and not an NSArray, as you are expecting.

Because it is returning an NSDictionary, there is no `objectAtIndex` method, and thus you get the error that you see.

Comment: [{
   "program": {
      "tmsId": "MV003297570000",
      "rootId": "8238130",
   },
   "startTime": "2012-08-11T10:20Z",
   "endTime": "2012-08-11T12:20Z",
   "duration": 120,
   "stationId": "34941",
   "callSign": "STZHD",
   "qualifiers": ["Stereo",
   "Enhanced",
   "HDTV",
   "DD 5.1"],
   "channels": ["1750"]
} This is my json data from API. Can you please suggest me how to pass this to NSDictionary and NSArray objects.

Comment: This is an NSDictionary. To get elements from it, you can do calls such as `[dict objectForKey:@"program"]`, which will return another NSDictionary object or `[dict objectForKey:@"qualifiers"]`, which will return an array.